Pdf automation with Python
I’ve been given a task to format multiple documents to a specific "in-house" style using Adobe Pro. The documents require formatting adjustments such as font changes, text alignment, and page layout tweaks to ensure consistency across various files.
I’m exploring ways to automate this process. I’m familiar with Python, and I’m wondering if it’s possible to use Python to assist with automating Adobe Pro tasks, particularly document formatting. Are there any Python libraries or tools that can integrate with Adobe Pro or make this process more efficient? Or, would it be better to use Python for certain steps and still rely on Adobe Pro for manual formatting?
I’m looking for recommendations on how best to approach this challenge.
So far my script doesn't even get the font correct...
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
import os


def generate_story():
    # Generate a simple short story
    story = """Once upon a time in a quiet village nestled between the hills, a young boy named Eli discovered an ancient key. 
    It was no ordinary key, for it glimmered faintly even in darkness. Curious and brave, Eli set out on an adventure 
    to uncover the door it belonged to. Through woods, rivers, and caves, the journey tested his courage and wit. 
    Finally, he found the door hidden beneath a great oak. Behind it lay a treasure not of gold, but of forgotten 
    wisdom, changing his life forever."""
    return story


def extract_template_styles(template_file):
    # Check if file exists
    if not os.path.exists(template_file):
        print(f"File no
        return None

    # Extract basic styles (dimensions, example text, etc.)
    reader = PdfReader(template_file)
    first_page = reader.pages[0]
    dimensions = first_page.mediabox
    text = first_page.extract_text()

    print("Extracted Text from Template:")
    print(text)

    print("\nPage Dimensions:")
    print(f"Width: {dimensions.width}, Height: {dimensions.height}")

    return {
        "dimensions": (dimensions.width, dimensions.height),
        "sample_text": text.strip().split("\n")[0]  # Example for styling, assume first line is a sample
    }


from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

def create_story_pdf(output_file, story, styles):
    # Use extracted dimensions for page layout
    page_dimensions = styles["dimensions"] if styles else letter
    sample_text = styles.get("sample_text", "") if styles else "Sample Header"

    c = canvas.Canvas(output_file, pagesize=page_dimensions)
    width, height = [float(dim) for dim in page_dimensions]  # Ensure dimensions are floats

    # Add a header (mimic template style if available)
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 16)
    c.drawString(50, height - 50, f"Header: {sample_text}")

    # Add the story body text
    c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)
    text_lines = story.split(". ")
    y_position = height - 100

    for line in text_lines:
        if y_position < 50:  # Check for page overflow
            c.showPage()
            y_position = height - 50
            c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)
        c.drawString(50, y_position, line.strip() + ".")
        y_position -= 20

    # Add a footer
    c.setFont("Helvetica", 10)
    c.drawString(50, 30, "Footer: Generated Story PDF")

    c.save()
    print(f"Styled Story PDF saved as {output_file}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Input PDF template file path
    template_file = input("Enter the path to your template PDF: ").strip()

    # / Users / snatch. / PycharmProjects / cvlibrary_auto_apply_job / clean_cv_2.pdf

    # Generate the story
    story = generate_story()

    # Extract template styles
    styles = extract_template_styles(template_file) if os.path.exists(template_file) else None

    # Output the story into a styled PDF
    output_file = "styled_story.pdf"
    create_story_pdf(output_file, story, styles)


if not os.path.exists(template_file):print(f"File no; return None
You never close the quote, so the rest of the code won't run

PyPDF2 is now pypdf
